# Sparql delete all children of node

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, fuseki, turtle-rdf

I have a question about the deletion of elements from a triplestore (fuseki) using SPARQL. I have stored the following elements in a graph:

```
<ChargingRequest/66769> a keak-ev:ChargingRequest ;
cnr:priority 2 ; 
keak-ev:chargingNeed [
 keak-eval:temporalContext [
    keak-time:start "2015-09-15T12:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime ;
    keak-time:end "2015-09-15T18:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime
  ] ;
  keak-eval:minimalValue [ # the powerMin
    qudt:unit qudt-unit:Watt ; 
    qudt:numericValue "7000"^^xsd:double 
  ] ;
] .
```

i would like to delete the node < ChargingRequest/66769> and all his properties.

**i tried**

```
   DELETE WHERE {
     <http://localhost:3030/keak/ChargingRequest/66769>  ?p ?o.
     keak-ev:chargingNeed ?p ?o
  }
```

**but it doesn't delete the nodes below**

```
keak-eval:temporalContext [
    keak-time:start "2015-09-15T12:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime ;
    keak-time:end "2015-09-15T18:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime
  ] ;
  keak-eval:minimalValue [ # the powerMin
    qudt:unit qudt-unit:Watt ; 
    qudt:numericValue "7000"^^xsd:double 
  ] ;
```

Please help me, and thank you for your time.

Comment: Why is is "/34" at one point and "/66769" at another?

Comment: it's a typing error, sorry, i corrected it , Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There are various way to do this but I think that 3 operations in one single request is the clearest:  note this is one request - see the ";" separating the operations.

```
  # Delete 3-deep
  DELETE {
    ?x ?p ?o 
  } WHERE {
     <http://localhost:3030/keak/ChargingRequest/66769>  ?q ?n1.
     ?n1 ?p1 ?x .
     ?x ?p ?o .
  } ;

  # Delete 2-deep
  DELETE {
    ?x ?p ?o 
  } WHERE {
     <http://localhost:3030/keak/ChargingRequest/66769>  ?q ?x.
     ?x ?p ?o .
  } ;
  # Delete immediate
  DELETE WHERE { <http://localhost:3030/keak/ChargingRequest/66769>  ?q ?x. }
```

Comment: Thank you AbdyS, but It's not working could you please check my comment below .

Comment: It does for me.

Check that relative URI `<ChargingRequest/66769>` in the data really is `<http://localhost:3030/keak/ChargingRequest/66769>`

Then do simple updates until something does happen to find out what is wrong in your setup.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work, this is the final solution

```
WITH <http://localhost:3030/keak/>  
 DELETE { 
  ?x ?p ?o 
} WHERE { 
  <http://localhost:3030/keak/ChargingRequest/66769>  ?q ?n1.
  ?n1 ?p1 ?x .
  ?x ?p ?o .
};

WITH <http://localhost:3030/keak/>  
 DELETE {
  ?x ?p ?o 
 } WHERE  {
   <http://localhost:3030/keak/ChargingRequest/66769>  ?q ?x.
   ?x ?p ?o .
 };

WITH <http://localhost:3030/keak/>  
 DELETE {
   <http://localhost:3030/keak/ChargingRequest/66769> ?q ?x 
 } WHERE  {
    <http://localhost:3030/keak/ChargingRequest/66769>  ?q ?x.
}
```

Thank you very much for your answer